# How to find VS Code keyboard shortcut conflict?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Command-Shift-F (default setting) for global find all. Extensively.

When I am editing a Java file, in addition to the problem that Java is on my screen, this shortcut doesn't work. Instead, Command-Shift-F will fold code in the current bracket to use less vertical whitespace.

I have never changed a default keyboard setting. As confirmed by Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and reviewing the right column.

How can I find which thing has commandeered my normal finding experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`:

- invoke `Record Keys` command (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on Windows):
- [image],
- press combination or chord,
- observe/change its `When` condition, remove or change through context menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`

toggle that on and then hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

in the `Output` you should get something like this:

> [2021-02-23 20:18:46.228] [renderer2] [info] [KeybindingService]: |
> Resolving ctrl+shift+J
> [2021-02-23 20:18:46.229] [renderer2] [info] [KeybindingService]: 
> From 2 keybinding entries, matched extension.convertCSSinJS, when:
> editorTextFocus, source: user extension
> paulmolluzzo.convert-css-in-js.

You can see that vscode is telling me that it resolved <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to a certain command `extension.convertCSSinJS` coming from the extension `paulmolluzzo.convert-css-in-js` which is the publisherName.name.  I don't have any extension named exactly that (beause an extension's `displayName` is probably rarely the same as its `name` - which can't have spaces) but you should be able to figure out which extension is the culprit from that info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's and example walk through how to solve a conflict:

I was having a problem with using system default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new tab when already on a tab while in vim mode. So to find the conflicts I did:

`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

Then from here you click on the keyboard icon to the right <kbd>⌨</kbd> to enter record keystroke mode and type combination you're looking for.

This showed me system and vim extension conflict. Since I never really want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a full new window, I was able to swap the system for that to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> by clicking on the edit button on the left when you select it.

Then I was able to change system default to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open new tab.  Now it works both in vim mode and as system default no conflicts.